# Moka7 - Java - Single bit Read - Write

Tags: java

Please, can you post an example to set/write a single bit on a DB ?

With this i write entire byte of the DB (i suppose)

```
ClientPlc.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, 200, 0, 1, Buffer);
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte[] data = new byte[2];
 res = client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, 59001, 0, 2, data); //I want to read DB7.DBD0 (it is a real)

 if (res == 0) {

    retEmerg01 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 0);
    retEmerg02 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 1);
    retEmerg03 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 2);
    retEmerg04 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 3);
    retEmerg05 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 4);
    retEmerg06 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 5);
    retEmerg07 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 6);
    retEmerg08 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 0, 7);
    retEmerg09 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 1, 0);
    retEmerg10 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 1, 1);
    retEmerg11 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 1, 2);
    retEmerg12 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 1, 3);
    retEmerg13 = S7.GetBitAt(data, 1, 4);

    }
```

You can do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! Is not simple find example for moka7.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this:

```
void WriteBit(int miDB, int miOffset, int miBit, boolean miVal){
    if (Connected){
      try{
          byte[] dataWrite = new byte[1];
          Client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, miDB, miOffset, 1, dataWrite); 
          //Keeping adjacent values
          S7.SetBitAt(dataWrite, 0, miBit, miVal);
          Client.WriteArea(S7.S7AreaDB, miDB, miOffset, 1,dataWrite);
      }catch(Exception e){println(e);}    
    }
  }

  boolean ReadBit(int miDB, int miOffset, int miBit){
    boolean miVal = false; 
    if (Connected){
        byte[] dataRead = new byte[1];  
        Client.ReadArea(S7.S7AreaDB, miDB, miOffset, 1, dataRead);
        miVal =S7.GetBitAt(dataRead, 0, miBit);            
        return miVal;
    }
    else return false;
  }
```